# Node.js Login Crashes App because Mysql "results" are "undefined"

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am extremely close to this working but for some reason the browser is rendering the standardized var of "results" as undefined.

```
`    var email = request.body.email;
var password = request.body.password;
if (name && password) {
    userDB.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = ? AND password = ?', [email, password], function (err, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {                         // <-- This is it
            request.session.loggedIn = true;
            request.session.email = email;
            //loggedIn = true;
            response.redirect('/');
        } else {
            response.render('test');
            loggedIn = false;
        }
        response.end();
    });
}`
```

Here is the actual err in the console:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I thought "results" and "fields" were standard.  What am I missing?

If need be I can always reply w/ more code to clarify.

Comment: Did you try console logging `err`?

Comment: Yeah I did and ended up resolving the issue.